# Is it possible to get the path of the included file from within the included file in Make?

Tags: makefile

In Gnumake, one can include a file as follows:

```
include some_file
```

I now wonder, is it possible to get the filepath of `some_file` from *within* that file, e.g. by doing `$(shell pwd)`? (I know that that command in particular doesn't work since it gets the path of the working directory, not the included file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MAKEFILE_LIST` variable to obtain that.  The last filename in that variable will be the current makefile, *as long as* you check it before you include any other files.  Basically every time make reads a new makefile the name of that makefile is added to the end of the variable, but no value is ever removed from the variable even after the makefile is no longer being parsed:

```
THIS_MAKEFILE := $(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

Comment: Cool! Now I no longer have to write it in manually in every module file that I include! =D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `readlink -f <file>` command to get the path of the file. You just have to know from within the file what the filename is, which I'm assuming you can hardcode.